# Postgress INET to Snowflake Compatible

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, greenplum

I need help in migrating a postgres function to snowflake function.

Currently, i have following function that takes an ip_address and returns the starting range of ip_address:

```
...
begin
  if (p_ip_address is not null) then
    return p_ip_address::inet - '0.0.0.0';
  else
    return null;
  end if;
end
...
```

I know we have [PARSE_IP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_ip.html) in snowflake that give JSON file but i need just one piece of this json (ipv4_range_start)

For Example:

```
Input  = 192.168.242.188
Output = 3232297472
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want peice of information, select it.

```
select parse_ip('127.0.0.0/24','INET') as a
    ,a:ipv4_range_end;
```

gives:

```
A   A:IPV4_RANGE_END
{    "family": 4,    "host": "127.0.0.0",    "ip_fields": [      2130706432,      0,      0,      0    ],    "ip_type": "inet",    "ipv4": 2130706432,    "ipv4_range_end": 2130706687,    "ipv4_range_start": 2130706432,    "netmask_prefix_length": 24,    "snowflake$type": "ip_address"  } 2130706687
```

Comment: Thanks Simeon for quick response. The data i have is in different format ('71.227.8.18').
 For my source data, it gives me NULLs
 {code}
 SELECT
   parse_ip('127.0.0.0/24','INET') AS a,
   parse_ip('71.227.8.18','INET')  AS b,
   a:ipv4_range_start AS s1,
   a:ipv4_range_end   AS e1,
   b:ipv4_range_start AS s2,
   b:ipv4_range_end   AS e2;   
 {code}

Comment: that's because `71.227.8.18` is a host address, not a network address. `127.0.0.0/24` is a network, and thus the function can give you the start address, which 127.0.0.0.0 and the end address is 127.0.0.255 because the /24 which sometime is also written in 255.255.255.0 shows which bits of the address are network and which are host addresses.. If you already know the mask for a network you can do the masking with the bit manipulation (but really PARSE_IP is simpler) however if you have no mask, there is no longer a defined standard for what used to be called "network class"